# How i get the user email address after login INSTAGRAM PHP API

Tags: php, instagram-api

I am using the instagram php api on my website.after logged in the following response returned by instagram api:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [meta] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => 200
    )
    [data] => stdClass Object
    (
        [username] => ankitchugh006
        [bio] => 
        [website] => 
        [profile_picture] => https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/anonymousUser.jpg
        [full_name] => 
        [counts] => stdClass Object
        (
            [media] => 0
            [followed_by] => 0
            [follows] => 1
        )
        [id] => 2137707201
    )
)
```

I am not getting the instagram loggedin useremail. How can i get the user email.any help will be deeply appriciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Instagram does not provide the user's email address.

Please check documentation at https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/#get_users

This is all Instagram outputs for a user object:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "1574083",
        "username": "snoopdogg",
        "full_name": "Snoop Dogg",
        "profile_picture": "http://distillery.s3.amazonaws.com/profiles/profile_1574083_75sq_1295469061.jpg",
        "bio": "This is my bio",
        "website": "http://snoopdogg.com",
        "counts": {
            "media": 1320,
            "follows": 420,
            "followed_by": 3410
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where mentioned in the documentation that the email will not provided?

Comment: Alex's answer is correct, it lists the fields that are available there, and https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/#scope tells you what scopes are available and email isn't included in them

Comment: So is there any way to get email?Should i ask to instagram for support regarding that?

Comment: You can try. Although I don't think you'd be the first. Best of luck! And if they do respond with a solution, please share it with us.

Comment: Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, Windows Live, Aol, and Yahoo all provide the email address when authenticating through Oauth or OpenId. But twitter and Instagram do not.

Comment: @sootsnoot Actually you can request twitter to whitelist your app to get the user's email address using this form : https://support.twitter.com/forms/platform

Comment: But is there anything similar for instagram?

Comment: @Alfie Wow, this would be great. I just submitted the form. But it wasn't clear to me exactly how to request it. First it asks for the application ID. I don't see that term anywhere in the application management console. So I guessed it was the decimal number in the url for my app's management console. Then it asked for permissions requested. If I look up "permissions" in their docs, there are just three: read, write, direct messages. So I just filled in "OAuth email scope". Hope that works! Thanks for the url!

Comment: @TommyBs I'm curious, whether he received any solution from Instagram)

Comment: I wouldn't know, maybe you should tag the original poster and ask them instead :)

Comment: Have you found out a solution?